# How to open PayPal in Swedish Language

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to add a link to my website on which if clicked, PayPal website is opened in Swedish Language. over that link I am using this code .

```
<a><input type="hidden" name="lc" value="SE"></a>
```

The anchor tag contains all required parameters. But this code is not working properly. Please help me doing this

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/se">PayPal in Swedish</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no flag to force a specific language. PayPal takes into account the language stored in the PayPal cookie, the language of the buyer's account (if logged in), the language of the buyer's browser, et cetera.

To add additional weight  to your choice, add:
 `<input type="hidden" name"lc" value="sv_SE">`.

In addition, change:
`<form method='POST' action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'>`

To:
`<form method='POST' action='https://www.paypal.com/se/cgi-bin/webscr'>`

Comment: Sir. This is what I am trying to say.. First I am using sandbox. Secondly I am not using form. I am using <a> Tag.. What to do??

Comment: You're using <input>, so you're by definition using a <form>. As for Sandbox: you can replace https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr with https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Comment: If you want to use a <a href>, use something similar to: `<a href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=youremail@here.tld&amount=0.99&lc=sv_SE&item_name=My%20item">Pay now</a>` -- however, keep in mind both cases are unsecured and is open to tampering of the amount to be paid.